# The method 'listen' isn't defined for the class 'Function'?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, listen

Hello everyone I am trying to build a flutter to display the latitude and the longitude but I still get an error here is the code :

[image: capture 1]

[image: capute]

```
 void initState(){
    super.initState();
    //Default variable set 0
    currentLocation['latitude'] = 0.0;
    currentLocation['longtitude'] = 0.0;

    initPlatformState();
    locationSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((Map<String, double> result){
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = result;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onLocationChanged` is a function, so you need to call it to get back the stream `onLocationChanged().listen` should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for me

```
    var location = new Location();
    location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      print(currentLocation.latitude);
      print(currentLocation.longitude);
    });
```